# How to get the hour from an NSDate in Swift 2?

Tags: nsdate, swift2

Before Swift 2 I used this extension to get the hour from a NSDate:

```
func hour() -> Int{
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: self)
        let hour = components.hour
        return hour
}
```

but now with Swift 2 I get the error for the let-components-line

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Is there a better known way now? Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Hour` instead of `.CalendarUnitHour`.

Comment: damn, that was easy. :-)